# Matplotlib rcParams not recognizing "Times New Roman" (mac High Sierra)

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I am trying to set the font of a matplotlib plot to Times New Roman. I have tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Times New Roman'
```

I believe this is the correct way to set the font, but I keep getting this error that the found is not found:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1238: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['Times New Roman'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
```

After some searching, I verified that I have the font downloaded. I tried opening a python shell and checking the contents of rcParams myself. Among a bunch of other font parameters, I curiously got a list of fonts in `font.serif` that contains Times New Roman.

```
          'font.serif': ['DejaVu Serif',
                         'Bitstream Vera Serif',
                         'Computer Modern Roman',
                         'New Century Schoolbook',
                         'Century Schoolbook L',
                         'Utopia',
                         'ITC Bookman',
                         'Bookman',
                         'Nimbus Roman No9 L',
                         'Times New Roman',
                         'Times',
                         'Palatino',
                         'Charter',
                         'serif'],
```

However, `font.family` only contained one item: `sans-serif`, when the [matplotlib documentation states](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) that there should be five values inside `font.family`. Has anybody run into this error before? How did you fix it?

Comment: I think on macs, there is no "Times New Roman", only "Times" by default. Maybe the installation has gone wrong? The `font.family` being set to `sans-serif` is correct (as is also seen from the link you share). It can be **one of** five different values.

Answer (score 9):

> However, font.family only contained one item: sans-serif, when the
>   matplotlib documentation states that there should be five values
>   inside font.family

No, `font.family` should contain one of those five values, namely the font family that you want to use.

You gotta make sure that the font family is set to *serif* and the font *Times New Roman* is at the top of the serif font list. It works like this:

```
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['Times New Roman'] + plt.rcParams['font.serif']
```

You technically don't need to append the rest of the list (the very last part). It simply provides a fallback for matplotlib if Times New Roman is actually not available.

Also see the [example in the docs](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/font_family_rc_sgskip.html).

Comment: Well, that's all good. But if *Times New Roman* is installed, `plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Times New Roman'` should work nonetheless. Or inversely, putting 'Times New Roman' at the top of the list, will not suddenly make this work if it didn't already work before.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that. According to the docs `plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Times New Roman'` doesn't work if `plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] == True` though. From the docs: "When text.usetex is False, font.family may also be one or more concrete font names."